# DB2 Transport Component is not registered correctly

Tags: db2, biztalk, biztalk-2006

I'm trying to test the `DB2 adapter` for **BizTalk 2006** (not R2).

While trying to configure an instance in an application, I get an error stating:

> DB2 Transport Component is not registered correctly

The enivronment is 2 BizTalk servers sharing a messagebox.

The DB2 adapter works fine on the first server. It is the second server I am having problems with.

I've exported the .msi files from the first server, then installed them onto the second server and imported them into BizTalk. All of the other adapters that I'm using work fine on both servers.

- Google searches don't bring up a whole lot regarding troubleshooting the BizTalk DB2 adapter.
- Further troubleshooting has shown that MS BizTalk Adapters for Host Systems is installed on both machines. However, it was only configured on the machine that is giving me the issue.
- I've unconfigured it, but that still has not helped.
- I've double checked tht version numbers of the .dll's for the DB2 adapter are the same on both servers, and made sure that they are installed in the GAC.
- None of this has helped.

Has anyone run into an issue like this before, or point me in the direction of where to look for BizTalk DB2 adapter troubleshooting guidence?

Comment: Is the platform the same between the two servers? Are they both x86?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the "registered" word appears, I think about the registration of COM components, not the installation of .NET assemblies. The underlying driver the DB2 adapter uses is the **Microsoft ODBC Driver for DB2**. You may want to check if your ODBC DSN control panel shows up that particular driver for you to configure a DSN.

I'd recommend a reinstallation for the Adapter pack for Host Systems.